# Scrollbars for dynamically added images

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I am using [**this**](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ajax.html) best JQuery scrollbar plugin.

This is the sample [**demo**](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ajax.html) on their site for loading dynamic content and appending scrollbars

I have a simple div and trying to upload some images using uploader and appending the uploaded images to this div

This is what I mean:

```
  uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function (up, file) {
          $('#paginationimages').append("<img class='LoadclickImage' align='left' 
          style='height:90px;width:120px;' src='Uploads/" + 
          $("<%=currentDirectory.ClientId%>").value + "/" + file.name + "' 
          width='120' height='90' rel='group1' href='Uploads/" + 
          $("<%=currentDirectory.ClientId%>").value + "/" + file.name + "'  
          data-full='Uploads/" + $("<%=currentDirectory.ClientId%>").value + "/"
          +file.name + "'>");
  });
```

Now how do I add scrollbars to this

Normally in the default example on the site we can use a class for the div as shown below and it adds a scrollbar for the div.But I would like to know how do I do that for the dynamic content.

```
<div class="scroll-pane-arrows">
</div>
```

And this is how my div looks:

```
<div id='paginationimages' class="thumbs">
</div>
```

Comment: Basically you need to call the jscroll function after the append is completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function (up, file) {
          $image = "<img class='LoadclickImage' align='left' 
          style='height:90px;width:120px;' src='Uploads/" + 
          $("<%=currentDirectory.ClientId%>").value + "/" + file.name + "' 
          width='120' height='90' rel='group1' href='Uploads/" + 
          $("<%=currentDirectory.ClientId%>").value + "/" + file.name + "'  
          data-full='Uploads/" + $("<%=currentDirectory.ClientId%>").value + "/"
          +file.name + "'>";
          $('#paginationimages').append($image).jScrollPane(...);
  });
```

Comment: @Kyle-Thanks for your time.It worked as what I expected.Cheers :)